# What techniques are used to style nativescript application to different screen sizes?

Tags: css, xml, nativescript, mobile-application

How to create a circular shape with StackLayout and it's size dependent on the screen size.

I have tried to set height and width to 100 and border-raduis to 50%,
but it's look bigger in small screens, and I have tried to set height to 15% and width to 25% and border-radius to 50% (according to the smallest screen I am testing on it) but it's give me an oval shape in taller screens.

I know there are screen qualifiers that I can use, but there are a lot of varieties of heights and widths which sounds not a great idea.

Are there any idea about how to achieve that without screen qualifiers in nativescript core?

**please note:** I am taking the circular shape as an example to understand how to style the whole application.

Comment: You may use [nativescript-platform-css](https://npm.proplugins.org/-/web/detail/@proplugins/nativescript-platform-css) plugin to add CSS for various screen ranges.

Comment: Its not updated to nativescript 6@Manoj

Comment: Indeed the one in the public npm, it's being updated & maintained in proplugins npm registry.